# What type of LED/lighting mechanism is this?

Tags: led

I am trying to identify the "name" of these LED components embedded in the monitor, so that I can purchase some for a medical device project.

[image]
[image]

What are those illuminated lights on top and the side of the monitors composed of?

Thanks!

Comment: These are probably custom per project/device. A similar thing might be a light pipe (usually dots).

Comment: Its just a standard LED with high enough brigthnes. You can use an SMD or THT LED, ultra bright and with a higher current through it. The brightness depends on the current.

Comment: The magic isn't so much in the LED ... It's in the design of the "lens".  The blue one is relatively easy to design, the yellow one a bit more difficult.  These can be "light pipes" or they could just be illuminated diffused windows (hate to say "lens" because they're not really lenses).   Honestly, best option, unless you wanna hire out the engineering, is buy something you think looks cool and take it apart, then copy it.  Not complex, Fisher Price does this with one LED...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vo26uN0loHM

Comment: @KyleB That's a great idea! Never thought Fisher Price could be useful oneday ^ ^